# JSON Warning in Flickr Photo Manager

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I am getting a warning in my iOS app.  It doesn't seem to be affecting performance in iOS 6 but my app is crashing when loading the photos from Flickr in iOS 7 beta 2 and I'm not sure if it's an issue with the beta or perhaps something to do with this warning but I'd like to get rid of the warning anyway.  Any help?

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSJSONWritingOptions' to different enumeration type 'NSJSONReadingOptions' (aka 'enum NSJSONReadingOptions')

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Comment: I wasn't saying the warning has anything to do with the beta.  I was saying that the fact that my collection view crashes on iOS 7 may be related to the beta since it doesn't crash on iOS 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple !! Just re-read the warning again. It says you are passing `NSJSONWritingOptions` option in options parameter while it expects `NSJSONReadingOptions`.

Change your line of code as below:

```
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Core Background works on iOS 6 and iOS 7 beta 1,2. The project was inspired by the Yahoo Weather iOS App. ObjectiveFlickr is leveraged for Flickr integration.

https://github.com/justinmfischer/core-background